# Could not load library dlopen error: libnvToolsExt.so.1

Tags: nvidia, ros2, nvidia-isaac

I am using the AGX Xavier with Jetpack 5.1.2, but when trying to run the apriltag example inside the provided container following the Isaac Ros documentation, i get the this error.

```
admin@usuario-desktop:/workspaces/isaac_ros-dev$ ros2 launch isaac_ros_apriltag isaac_ros_apriltag.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/admin/.ros/log/2024-01-19-10-10-40-180815-usuario-desktop-6519
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [component_container_mt-1]: process started with pid [6534]
[component_container_mt-1] [INFO] [1705655442.068763895] [apriltag_container]: Load Library: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libapriltag_node.so
[component_container_mt-1] [ERROR] [1705655442.108378693] [apriltag_container]: Failed to load library: Could not load library dlopen error: libnvToolsExt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-humble-rcutils-5.1.4/src/shared_library.c:99
[ERROR] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Failed to load node 'apriltag' of type 'nvidia::isaac_ros::apriltag::AprilTagNode' in container '/apriltag_container': Failed to load library: Could not load library dlopen error: libnvToolsExt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-humble-rcutils-5.1.4/src/shared_library.c:99
```

I tried to re-install jetpack 5.1.2, and follow the documentation several times, but nothing seems to work.